# Controlling a remote Linux machine with dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, rdp, nx

I have a remote Linux VM that runs Ubuntu 12.04. I currently use NX to connect to the remote machine and work on it in a GUI environment. On my host computer, I have 2 monitors of different sizes (22" and 24"). When I choose "Fullscreen on all screens" in NX it simply assumes there is one large screen and the top of the 22" screen is cut off.

What I want is a client that can spread over both of my screens and that the Linux machine will *know* that I have two monitors and behave accordingly. Is that possible with NX, or some other client?

Answer (score 0):

NX is difficult with multiple monitors. Furthermore, it is only supported until Ubuntu 12.04, but not in newer versions. You'll probably wanna tryout other VNC servers like `x11vnc` for instance. Try out http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-xinerama as well.

Hope I could help! Don't forget to vote! ;)

Answer (score 0):

[x2go](http://www.x2go.org) also uses NX technology and has support for Xinerama. This should solve your problem.